# Variable used within its own initial value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to append values inside of an array of the type UIImageView. It values that needs to be added depends on other values. This is my declaration of my array:

```
var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "")!]
```

And this is my code:

```
            let cardIndex = playableCards.index (where: { $0.currentTitle! == button.currentTitle! })
            {
                images[cardIndex] = [UIImage(named: "")!]

            }
```

No I am wondering what I am doing wrong here. I just want to add values to that index of that cardIndex is telling me. I also tried adding this before:

```
    while howManyCardsNeedsToBeUnlocked != 0{
        images.append(UIImage(named: "")!)
        howManyCardsNeedsToBeUnlocked - 1
    }
```

So that images always have an index. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playableCards.index (where: { $0.currentTitle! == button.currentTitle! })` returns an optional, so you need to unwrap the value before you can use it. I think the compiler is giving you the wrong error and should be telling you to unwrap the value. I unwrap it below with `if let`.

```
if let cardIndex = playableCards.index(where: { $0.currentTitle! == button.currentTitle! }) {
    images[cardIndex] = UIImage(named: "")!
}
```

Comment: Wow it actually works... Not the first time Swift is buggy >:(... Can you edit your answer to UIImage(named: "")! so without the "[]"? I did not have time to test it, but Swift is giving me errors when using the "[]" 6 minutes I have to wait to tick on the green mark

Comment: It's not a swift bug, it's you omitting "if" and Swift doing it's best to figure out what you really meant.

Comment: This were some long 6 minutes :P